# cocos2d-X 3.X render texture produce ugly copy?

Tags: ios, screenshot, antialiasing, cocos2d-x-3.0, render-to-texture

I am new to cocos2dX

I've searched stackoverflow with the related keywords but can't find any relevant content. So I am posting a new one.

I am using renderTexture to enhance the performance of my app, the image below is one cell(menuItem) of a table(menu), I sort of "flatten" it so it wont contain many sprites / text fields in one cell.

But the output looks jaggy.
Is there any ways to have a better output ?

And is that the ugly output caused by the scale factor ?

original

[image: original]

render Texture

[image: render texture]

Comment: Hi Kit Man, when you link images in your posts, try to use the provided imgur uploader (visible in the text editor when asking a question) :)

Comment: there are Texture2D::PixelFormat and uDepthStencilFormat parameter to RenderTexture create, try playing with those values, make sure pixel format is at 32 bit RGBA. Also, if you have set antialiasing to true, it could change the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

found out the issue is related to the scale-factor of cocos2d-X.
solution:

1. Scale up the content to its original width and height (cancel the auto scaling in cocos2d-X)
2. capture the content's screenshot with the exact same dimension REnderTexture
3. create a sprite from the capture
4. scale back down the resulting sprite with cocos2d-X's scale factor

hope that will help someone in need too

Comment: It does not help me. I have the same kind problem. See here: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/3-0-beta-2-rendertexture-stretching/11618/18

Comment: I've done the same, it works on simulator but sprite still looks jagged on iPhone after scaling down.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why just rendered sprite is not "pixel perfect", but my solution is:

```
renderTexture->getSprite()->getTexture()->setAntiAliasTexParameters()
```